# Retrieve value from column in table using PDO and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im using the following to log my users in,

```
/*** select the users name from the database ***/
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM access_users 
    WHERE id = :phpro_user_id");

    $stmt->bindParam(':phpro_user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

    $username = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    if($username == false)
    {
    $message = 'Access Error';
    }
    else
    {
        // done
    }
```

I want to retrieve the users `level` value, which is a column in my table only im unsure how to do this with PDO?

I've tried...

```
print $result->level;
```

Comment: Did you tried $username['level']? Cuz you save the result into $username.

Comment: Your code is extremely inconsistent. where did you get that $result? Why do you want level in a $username variable?

Answer (score 2):

As it's impossible to get from your question, what column you ant to retrieve, assuming it is called "username":

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM access_users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']));
$username = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

This is how `fetchColumn()` works.

But if you want to get all the user info, **and** among it, level and username, you have to retrieve usual way, a whole row.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM access_users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if(!$row['level'])
{
    $message = 'Access Error';
}
echo "Hello ".$row['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user_id,level FROM access_users 
    WHERE id = :phpro_user_id");

//rest of the code up until here

$result = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);

print("level= $result\n");
```